# How to show this matrix limit?

Tags: limits, matrix-calculus, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ be a $m\times n(m<n)$ matrix, $\mu>0$. $A$ is a full rank matrix. I am interested in showing that $$\lim_{\mu\to 0} (A^TA+\mu I)^{-1}A^T= A^T(AA^T)^{-1},$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Could you provide insights or a step-by-step proof for this limit expression?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\:A,B^T\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n}\:$ and assume the existence of a function $f(z)$ which is well defined for both of the matrix arguments $(AB)$ and $(BA)$.

Then there is a wonderful (yet almost trivial) identity due to Higham
$$f(BA)\;B = B\;f(AB)$$

In the current problem, take $f(z) = (z+\mu)^{-1}$ and $B=A^T$ to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\lim_{\mu\to0}\;(A^TA+\mu I)^{-1}A^T
 &= \lim_{\mu\to0}\,A^T(AA^T+\mu I)^{-1} &= A^T(AA^T)^{-1} \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use singular value decomposition to show the limit.
Assume $A=U[\Sigma_m, 0] V^T$,  where $ U$ is a $ m\times m$
real orthogonal  matrix, $\Sigma_m=\text{diag}(\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_m)$ is a $m\times m$ diagonal matrix with non-negative real numbers on the diagonal, V is a $n\times n$  real orthogonal  matrix. So,
\begin{align} &\lim_{\mu\to 0} (A^TA+\mu I)^{-1}A^T\\
=&\lim_{\mu\to 0} \left(V\left(\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_m^T\Sigma &0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}+I\right)V^T\right)^{-1}V\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_m^T\Sigma &0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}U^T\\
=&\lim_{\mu\to 0} \left(V\left(\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2+\mu & \\
&\sigma_2^2+\mu \\
&&\ddots \\
&&& \sigma_m^2+\mu\\
&&&& \mu\\
&&&&& \mu\\
&&&&&&\ddots \\
&&&&&&&\mu \\
\end{bmatrix}+I\right)V^T\right)^{-1} V\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_m^T\Sigma &0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}U^T \\
=&\lim_{\mu\to 0} V\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_1^2+\mu} & \\
&\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_2^2+\mu}  \\
&&\ddots \\
&&& \frac{\sigma_m}{\sigma_m^2+\mu} \\
&&&&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}U^T\\
=&V\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_m^{-1}\\
&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}U^T\end{align}

and
\begin{align}
&A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\\
=&V\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_m^T\Sigma &0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}U^T (U\Sigma_m\Sigma^T_mU^T)^{-1}\\
=&V\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_m^T\Sigma &0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}U^T U(\Sigma_m\Sigma^T)^{-1}_mU^T\\
=&V\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_m^{-1}\\
&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}U^T
\end{align}
So, $$\lim_{\mu\to 0} (A^TA+\mu I)^{-1}A^T =A^T(AA^T)^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is equivalent to
$$\lim_{\mu\to 0^+} (A^TA+\mu I)^{-1}A^TAA^T= A^T$$
i.e. (since $A$ is full rank)
$$\lim_{\mu\to 0^+} (A^TA+\mu I)^{-1}A^TAA^TA= A^TA.$$
Since $A^TA$ is diagonalizable, this is equivalent to
$$\lim_{\mu\to 0^+}\frac{\lambda^2}{\lambda+\mu}=\lambda$$
for each of its eigenvalues $\lambda$.

This last identity is obvious.

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't this answer the simplest one?